# Can I receive all messages except for new messages from AWS SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

I am using AWS SQS with nodejs and python(boto3).

Numerous messages are constantly coming to AWS SQS.

I want to get only the messages that have just been received.

For example, if there are 100 messages in SQS when I poll, and 100 messages come after I poll, I would like to get only first 100 messages.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can specify number of messages to be processed at once, but sqs is just a queue and sqs doesn't care about when the messages arrived.

Comment: Is your code polling SQS or is your code actually a Lambda function that is triggered by the Lambda service when message arrive in the SQS queue?

Comment: You seem to be describing how SQS works by default. What is the _actual_ problem that you're seeing? Hint: it's probably something you can solve by increasing the visibility timeout.

Comment: When retrieving messages from an Amazon SQS queue, you can retrieve a maximum of 10 at a time. If it is vital that the messages are retrieved in the same order that they were sent, you can create a `FIFO` (first-in-first-out) SQS queue. A non-FIFO queue is generally in-order, but it is not guaranteed.